# Login in vbulletin without password (username and hash only)

Tags: authorization, vbulletin

All day I was looking an answer on this question:
How to log in vbulletin, without using password.

For example I send username in request to module and it logs user in.

All I found is:

```
verify_authentication('username', 'pass', '', '', TRUE, TRUE);
process_new_login('', TRUE, '');
```

or

```
verify_authentication('username', '', 'md5(pass)', 'md5(pass)', TRUE, TRUE);
process_new_login('', TRUE, '');
```

But I haven't got no password neither md5 hash, I have only `md5(md5(pass+salt))`.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found solution. All we need is user id.

```
    $vbulletin->userinfo = fetch_userinfo($userid);
    vbsetcookie('userid', $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'], true, true, true);
    vbsetcookie('password', md5($vbulletin->userinfo['password'] . COOKIE_SALT), true, true, true);
    exec_unstrike_user($vbulletin->userinfo['username']);
    $logintype = ($vbulletin->userinfo['usergroupid'] == '6') ? 'cplogin' : '';
    process_new_login($logintype, TRUE, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.
A possible solution is at the end, but first, here's how the password is checked.

`md5(md5(pass+salt))` is the way the original text password is stored in the database.

When you log in through the login fields at the top of the forum, JavaScript is used to run `md5(password)` before the username and password are posted to the server. If JavaScript isn't enabled, the plain text password is posted.

The `verify_authentication()` function tries three approaches to validating the password:

```
if (
  $vbulletin->userinfo['password'] != iif($password AND !$md5password, md5(md5($password) . $vbulletin->userinfo['salt']), '') AND
  $vbulletin->userinfo['password'] != iif($md5password, md5($md5password . $vbulletin->userinfo['salt']), '') AND
  $vbulletin->userinfo['password'] != iif($md5password_utf, md5($md5password_utf . $vbulletin->userinfo['salt']), '')
)
```

---

If the plaintext password (`$password`) was sent, it passes it through `md5(md5(pass+salt))` and is compared with the hashed password from the database:

```
$vbulletin->userinfo['password'] != iif($password AND !$md5password, md5(md5($password) . $vbulletin->userinfo['salt']), '')
```

---

If the password was hashed by JavaScript (`$md5password`), it is passed through `md5(pass+salt)` and is compared with the hashed password from the database:

```
$vbulletin->userinfo['password'] != iif($md5password, md5($md5password . $vbulletin->userinfo['salt']), '')
```

---

If the password was hashed by JavaScript and UTF is being used (`$md5password_utf`), it is passed through `md5(pass+salt)` and is compared with the hashed password from the database:

```
$vbulletin->userinfo['password'] != iif($md5password_utf, md5($md5password_utf . $vbulletin->userinfo['salt']), '')
```

---

If you want a certain username to be able to log in without a password, you could try adding a plugin using the `login_failure` hook. Your pluin could check the username and if it matches the particular one you're using, you could continue the log in process. The plugin would contain:

```
if ($vbulletin->GPC['vb_login_username'] == 'your_username')
{
  exec_unstrike_user($vbulletin->GPC['vb_login_username']);

  process_new_login($vbulletin->GPC['logintype'], $vbulletin->GPC['cookieuser'], $vbulletin->GPC['cssprefs']);

  do_login_redirect(); 
}
```